# Join query results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am working in a MySQL database.

I have three tables. 1 , 2 & 3

I would like to join the result of joining tables 2 & 3 to table 1 on an id. I would like to keep all entries for table 1 and after join the result of 2 & 3 on the call id and where it doesn't match have a null value.

```
Table 1 has callid
Table 2 has callid and invoiceid
Table 3 has invoiceid and customerid
```

So join table 2 & 3 on invoiceid and filter by customerid = xyz the result of that is then joined to table 1 on callid. Table 1 would also have a Where clause filtering the on a date

result would look like this

```
callid   customerid
  123       xyz
  124       xyz
  125       null
  126       xyz
```

thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are describing `left join`:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.callid = t2.callid left join
     table3 t3
     on t3.invoiceid = t2.invoiceid;
```

You can filter on customer id in the `on` clause:

```
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.callid = t2.callid left join
     table3 t3
     on t3.invoiceid = t2.invoiceid and t3.customerid = ?;
```

However, this might not be exactly what you want.  You might want to filter for the inner join and then do the `left join`:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 left join
     (table2 t2 join
      table3 t3
      on t3.invoiceid = t2.invoiceid
     )
     on t1.callid = t2.callid and
        t3.customerid = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.
 I have tried that with left join, but I forgot to mention that Table 2 callid is not distinct and by joining 2 & 3 will make the result have callid a s distinct due to the customer filter

Comment: You Sir are a genius. thank you! It works